# Freezing column headers while scrolling in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a simple table in ssrs with a single header row and no grouping. I want to freeze the columns while scrolling. I have set the properties of table(Fixed column headers AS true) . I have also checked the checkbox which says"Headers should be visible while scrolling" but still it doesn't work.

What should i do?

Comment: It's much harder than it should be! Here's a [complete explanation](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s147/scrolling-page-titles-ssrs.htm).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this can be fixed by setting the FixedData property to True in Advanced Mode.  To get to Advanced Mode, click the down arrow on the grouping pane, select Advanced Mode, then select Details and check the properties there.

Comment: Unfortunately, the bidn.com domain is for sale. The link given by Hari Gillala is dead.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way I found is [**this**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934257%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) one. The Fixed Group property did not work for me.