# SSRS: How to display column header on more than one page

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to have column header in more than 1 page? For now, I'm getting the header only on the first page. Is it possible to get the table header on every page?

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | 
+------+------+------+------+------+
|      |      |      |      |      |

------------------------------------
                  Page 1 of 10 pages


+------+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | 
+------+------+------+------+------+
|      |      |      |      |      |

------------------------------------
                 Page 2 of 10 pages
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: please refer this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781592/freezing-column-headers-while-scrolling-in-ssrs

Comment: Please refer to this url if you are using tablix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285923/tablix-repeat-header-rows-on-each-page-not-working-report-builder-3-0

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is right click on table or matrix- you can find a option row headers or column headers. Check the boxes (Repeat Headers rows on each page and Keep header visible while scrolling) and preview the report

Comment: I've checked those 2 options without any luck.

Comment: it should work .if not working please follow below link. you have to do for all groups and detail one.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207045.aspx